# SQL Insert in Java class throws error on the SQL Statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I keep getting an error on my statement when running the postmethod of my servlet. However, when I simply try to do it in the database directly it works just fine.

I'm using a tomcat 9 server; and postgres database. Java Openlogic 11;

The message I'm getting is:
*ERROR: column "doe" does not exist
Position: 61*
Which refers to the value I'm trying to insert.

What am I missing here? I'm still learning so any and all information is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        
        Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        
              int result =  stmt.executeUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO testinserts (lastname, firstname, city) VALUES ("+ lastname + "," + firstname + "," + location + ");");
            
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            if(result > 0){
                writer.println("<H1>" + firstname + " created " + "</H1>");
            } else {
                writer.println("<H1>" + "none created " + "</H1>");    
            }
            
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
           writer.println(ex.getMessage());
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = ex.getStackTrace();
            
            writer.println("<HTML>");
            for(StackTraceElement st : stackTrace){
                writer.println("<p style=\"color: red\">" + st.toString() + "</p>");
            }
            writer.println("</HTML>");

    }
```

Comment: after adding proper quoting (string values need to be enclosed in ' ), remove the ending ; from your statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other (accepted) answer **is a security leak and will get your database p0wned**.

Do not do that.

There are multiple things wrong here.

### Fix the security leak

Let's say I visit that the form where you type in your real name. I type in this gigantic thing:

```
Elvis', '', ''); DROP TABLE testinserts CASCADE; EXECUTE '/bin/bash -c "rm -rf /*"'; --
```

It's valid SQL (assuming an SQL engine that has execute). Your insert statement ends up looking like:

```
INSERT INTO testinserts (lastname, firstname, city) VALUES 
('Elvis', '', ''); DROP TABLE testinserts CASCADE; 
EXECUTE '/bin/bash -c "rm -rf /*"'; --', 
'whatever I typed in for firstname', 'whatever I typed for city');
```

`--` is SQL-ese for 'comment', so everything after it is completely ignored. In other words, that inserts 1 row, then drops the entire table, then formats your harddrive.

**There is no escaping this**. Instead, the fix is to **never ever ever** inject user input straight into your database. In other words, **all SQL strings must be constant strings**. So how do you get the names in there? With PreparedStatement, and question marks:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO testinserts(lastname, firstname, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, lastName);
ps.setString(2, firstName);
ps.setString(3, city);
ps.execute();
```

If I now type in all that in your form, then all that just gets stored as the first name. The *point* of PreparedStatement is that the .setString command sets the *entire string*, it doesn't just swap out the first question mark for what I typed. The security leak is completely fixed now.

### Resources

A second issue is resources. Your DB engine only lets you open up a handful of connections before it just starts denying them. Therefore you **must** close it. If you don't close it, after 20 or so inserts your java app (or, for that matter, any other app) can no longer connect to the DB because the DB thinks it is 'too busy', as there are still 20 open connections. Those connections are long abandoned, but java doesn't garbage collect on the spot - those objects are just lying about doing nothing, but the DB engine doesn't know that.

You could call `close()`, but what if your code throws an exception, or you write a return; and you forgot that you have now forgotten to close?

Solution is try-with-resources. Note that Connection, *and* PreparedStatement, *and* ResultSet are ALL resources that need this treatment:

```
try (Connection con = ....;
PreparedStatement ps = ....;) {

ps.setString(1, ...);
ps.setString(2, ...);
ps.setString(3 ...);
ps.execute();
}
```

That `try(){}` construct tells java: Run the creation stuff (the creation of the objects `con` and `ps` are referring to), and then run the stuff in the `{}`, but no matter how the code *exits* those `{}`, be it 'naturally' (run to the end of it), be it via control flow (break, continue, or `return;` out of it), or via exceptions (throw something), first call `close()` on those resources and only then continue.

Comment: This is a very fine explanation, and very clear! Thank you. I was already wondering about the practice of directly calling SQL from the servlet as a practice. And this post also made the injection and connection much clearer! You, have a new fan.

Answer (score -2):

Your query seems to be fine, so it must be a problem with the database you're trying to insert.
Can you specify the schema you're trying to do the insert on? For example:
"INSERT INTO test.testinserts (lastname, firstname, city) VALUES ("+ lastname + "," + firstname + "," + location + ");"

Also, check your DB connection. For example, try to manually insert some data and then query it from your code.

Edit: As said in other posts, this was made to check the example exposed.
You should build querys doing VALUES (?, ?, ?) and then use stm.setString(1, lastname), stm.setString(2, firstname), etc to **avoid SQL injection**.

Comment: Your values need quoting. Hint - use a `PreparedStatement` properly

Comment: I was refering to his example, where the values are local variables. But yes, if that wasn't the case, you would need quoting.

Comment: @Guillermo - The connection is good; I've got it set so the initial display of the servlet shows me the resultset of the table.

Comment: Adding quoting now... How stupid am I going to feel?

Comment: *Don't* add quoting actually. Do what i said or you might get some nasty sql injection going on

Comment: @g00se, do you have any documentation regarding this? Or any workarounds? By the way, it's working now. I feel very stupid... Sorry everyone.

Comment: `try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO testinserts (lastname, firstname, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?);")) { // the rest }`

Comment: So try with resources migates the changes of a SQL injection?

Comment: *So try with resources migates the changes of a SQL injection?* No, that mitigates the chances of resource leakage. It's the `PreparedStatement` that does that